# Limit length PdfPCellEvent

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I have a Table in my PDF Form and I have used PdfpCellevent helper to insert text fields in rows, however i can enter values into the text field and it just flows over in to the non-visible part of the cell field.

How can to limit the length to visible area in a pdfPcellevent in itext?

```
static class MyCellField implements PdfPCellEvent{
    public String fieldname;
    public MyCellField(String fieldname){
    this.fieldname= fieldname;
    }
    @Override 

  public void cellLayout(PdfPCell cell, Rectangle rectangle, PdfContentByte[] canvases) {
    final PdfWriter writer = canvases[0].getPdfWriter();
    final TextField textField = new TextField(writer, rectangle, fieldname);
    try {
        final PdfFormField field = textField.getTextField();
        writer.addAnnotation(field);
    } catch (final IOException | DocumentException ioe) {
        throw new ExceptionConverter(ioe);
    }
}
} 

  private static PdfPCell createPdfCell(String phrase, String eventValue){
        PdfPCell pdfCell = new PdfPCell();
        pdfCell.addElement(new Phrase(phrase, FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES, 11)));
        pdfCell.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
        pdfCell.setBorderColor(BaseColor.BLACK);
        pdfCell.setPadding(2);
        pdfCell.getFixedHeight();
        pdfCell.setCellEvent(new MyCellField(eventValue));
        pdfCell.setRowspan(3);
        return pdfCell;
}
```

The picture below display what is currently does:

[image]

and the one below is what I expect:

[image]

Comment: Please show us your code and the expected behavior

Comment: You are probably using `ColumnText.showTextAligned()` instead of creating a `ColumnText`, setting the column size, adding content and using the `go()` method. I agree with Alexey. You shouldn't expect a more elaborate answer if you don't show any code.

Comment: Now it's clear. You have a single-line field and you want it to be a multi-line field. That's easy.

Answer (score 0):

You say you want this:

[image]

In other words, you want multi-line text fields.

You get this:

[image]

These are single-line fields, and that's normal, because you create your field like this:

```
TextField textField = new TextField(writer, rectangle, fieldname);
PdfFormField field = textField.getTextField();
```

You should create your field like this instead:

```
TextField textField = new TextField(writer, rectangle, fieldname);
textField.setOptions(TextField.MULTILINE);
PdfFormField field = textField.getTextField();
```

The option `TextField.MULTILINE` will change your single-line text fields into multi-line text fields.

See the [official documentation](http://developers.itextpdf.com/) for some more [multi line field](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/form-examples/multiline-fields#1180-readonlyfield2.java) examples.